# List multiple values one by one Mysql query and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table.

```
Id              meta

1               {"stars":["Lucille Ball","Desi Arnaz","Vivian Vance","William Frawley"]}
2               {"stars":["Carol","Tudor Mandia"]}
3               {"stars":["Jony","Vandame"]}
```

i wana get this :

```
        Lucille Ball
        Desi Arnaz
        Vivian Vance
        William Frawley
        Carol
        Tudor Mandia
        Jony
        Vandame
```

in that order.

How to do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must do JSON decode of each meta value and then to get needed values from the arrays:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT Id, meta FROM table1 ORDER BY Id";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $meta = json_decode($row['meta'], true);
        foreach($meta['stars'] as $key=>$value){
            echo $value.'<br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Output is:

```
Lucille Ball
Desi Arnaz
Vivian Vance
William Frawley
Carol
Tudor Mandia
Jony
Vandame
```